# Java Error While Running Flutter App on Emulator

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

After trying to run my flutter app from vs code in android emulator Nexus 5X, I am getting an error which says that I have to setup JDK and I make it's Path Variables for User section and now I am getting a tons of java errors while trying to run my flutter app. Please Help

Comment: Have you tried setting up the JDK and making sure your Path is pointed to it?

Comment: Yes, I have done that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run flutter using android java JDK and Android SDK is essential.These are main steps.

- Download JAVA JDK from oracle official website and install it
  according to your platform(Windows,Ubuntu,Mac,etc.).And set up JDK
  too.
- Download and install android studio and It will automatically set up
  android sdk for our development.

Think your problem is environment path problem or missing JDK.So set up Java JDK first.

Comment: I have installed JAVA JDK and Android SDK already using Android Emulator but having that trouble. I think maybe there's a problem in the Path

Comment: yeah.what is your os? set global paths correctly.It will fix this problem.

Comment: Windows 10, Changed the Path variable of JAVA JDK from user variables to system variables. Now getting some less errors of gradle but the problem is still don't get fix `BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`

Comment: run flutter clean and re run the project. if that occures again check the issue using flutter doctor command.

Comment: Doctor gives exclamation mark on android toolchain and on android studio and cross on android license status

Comment: Ok, I have successfully fixed all problems of doctor just 1 remains there's an exclamation mark on Android studio

Comment: put that here. what does it say?

Comment: `[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1052], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[√] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.`

Comment: Ok bro I have reinstalled the Android studio again it get located now but sdk got unlocated I locate it again using `flutter config --android-sdk` but it says that platform directory in it is empty

Comment: check your environment varibles ANDROID_HOME is located

Comment: Ok bro it's fixed now  Thanks for your help 